# Periodically reading output from async background scripts

Tags: json, bash, asynchronous, ipc

*Context: I'm making my own i3-Bar script to read output from other (asynchronous) scripts running in background, concatenate them and then `echo` them to i3-Bar itself.*

The way I'm passing outputs is in plain files, and I guess (logically) the problem is that the files are sometimes read and written at the same time. The best way to reproduce this behavior is by *suspending* the computer and then waking it back up - I don't know the exact cause of this, I can only go on what I see from my debug log files.

**Main Code:** *Added comments for clarity*

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd "${0%/*}";

trap "kill -- -$$" EXIT; #The bg. scripts are on a while [ 1 ] loop, have to kill them.

rm -r ../input/*;
mkdir ../input/; #Just in case.

for tFile in ./*; do
    #Run all of the available scripts in the current directory in the background.
    if [ $(basename $tFile) != "main.sh" ]; then ("$tFile" &); fi;
done;

echo -e '{ "version": 1 }\n['; #I3-Bar can use infinite array of JSON input.

while [ 1 ]; do

    input=../input/*; #All of the scripts put their output in this folder as separate text files

    input=$(sort -nr <(printf "%s\n" $input));

    output="";

    for tFile in $input; do
        #Read and add all of the files to one output string.
        if [ $tFile == "../input/*" ]; then break; fi;
        output+="$(cat $tFile),";
    done;

    if [ "$output" == "" ]; then
        echo -e "[{\"full_text\":\"ERR: No input files found\",\"color\":\"#ff0000\"}],\n";
    else
        echo -e "[${output::-1}],\n";
    fi;

    sleep 0.2s;
done;
```

**Example Input Script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd "${0%/*}";

while [ 1 ]; do
    echo -e "{" \
        "\"name\":\"clock\"," \
        "\"separator_block_width\":12," \
        "\"full_text\":\"$(date +"%H:%M:%S")\"}" > ../input/0_clock;
    sleep 1;
done;
```

## The Problem

The problem isn't the script itself, but the fact, that i3-Bar receives a malformed JSON input (-> parse error), and terminates - I'll show such log later.

Another problem is, that the background scripts should run asynchronously, because some need to update every 1 second nad some only every 1 minute, etc. So the use of a FIFO isn't really an option, unless I create some ugly inefficient hacky stuff.

I know there is a need for IPC here, but I have no idea how to *effieciently* do this.

**Script output from randomly crashing - waking up error looks the same**

```
[{ "separator_block_width":12, "color":"#BAF2F8", "full_text":"192.168.1.104 "},{ "separator_block_width":12, "color":"#BAF2F8", "full_text":"100%"}],

[{ "separator_block_width":12, "color":"#BAF2F8", "full_text":"192.168.1.104 "},,],
```

(Error is created by the second line) 
As you see, the main script tries to read the file, doesn't get any output, but the comma is still there -> malformed JSON.

Comment: Consider using `jq` to generate and merge your JSON files. `jq --slurp '.' ../input/*` alone would merge your input files into a single JSON array.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate error is easy to fix: don't append an entry to `output` if the corresponding file is empty:

```
for tFile in $input; do
    [[ $tFile != "../input/*" ]] &&
      [[ -s $tFile ]] &&
      output+="$(<$tFile),"
done
```

There is a potential race condition here, though. Just because a particular input file *exists* doesn't mean that the data is fully written to it yet. I would change your input scripts to look something like

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd "${0%/*}";

while true; do
    o=$(mktemp)
    printf '{"name": "clock", "separator_block_width": 12, "full_text": %(%H:%M:%S)T}\n' > "$o"
    mv "$o" ../input/0_clock
    sleep 1
done
```

Also, `${output%,}` is a safer way to trim a trailing comma when necessary.

Comment: I tried checking if the file exists before, but I didn't know about the '-s' option, thank you. And I edited my scripts according to your recommendations.

Comment: Well, I gotta say, It nearly worked, but once every 10-20 minutes it does the same thing again, nothing changed, just the error rate. It's about every 8000 cycles now. I'm really considering a different approach - IPC, but I have no idea how to do that,